# Python 3 - What is the best way for executing multiple queue consumers?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq

I'm learning python so I'm not expert.

I have 3 different scripts that basically do the same thing.
Each script attaches a consumer to a RabbitMQ queue and processes the queue.

I would like to build a wrapper to run these 3 scripts and build a deamon that start automatically with the system.

My wrapper also should have the logic for manage the errors and start a child process if one of the subprocesses dies and collect the output for each subprocess.

The structure is something like that:

```
main.py
|-->consumer_one.py
|-->consumer_two.py
|-->consumer_three.py
```

Could you suggest if exist a package that manages the process forking in a simple way?

Thank you so mutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few test, I think the best solution is to install the package http://supervisord.org/

In my scenario, I can manage easier the restart if the services die, also, I can manage differents logs for process and attach specifics event listeners.

Supervisor has a lot of good functions to manage asynchronous services.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the concurrent.future standard library module.
It is quite simple to use and very easy to manage

Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
#import consumer_one
#import consumer_two 

import a
import time

consumer_one, consumer_two = a,a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    jobs = [pool.submit(module.start) for module in (consumer_one, consumer_two)] 


    print(jobs)
    j1, j2 = jobs
    print(j1.running())

    while all(j.running() for j in jobs):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("all is well...")

    print("some one has died!") #I guess now you can do something much more clever :)
    pool.shutdown()
    exit(1)
```

Read the docs for more info:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: I didn't solve because this line

`jobs = [pool.submit(module.start) for module in (events_process, items_process)]`

start the consumer_one and inside the consumer_a the instruction from RabbitMQ

`channel.basic_consume(consumer.consume, queue=consumer.get_name(), no_ack=True)
        channel.start_consuming()`

stop the execution until the queue receives a message ;(

I need to figure out how I can ignore the process wait.

Anyway thank you